# Labeling 3d axes in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I assume this is a simple fix.  I'm trying to replace integer values in a 3d bar chart in matplotlib with string names, and the last one inexplicably won't show:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,8.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for c, z in zip([qwer for qwer in ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']*20][:len(sss.keys())], sss.keys()):
    xs = np.array(sss[z].keys())
    ys = np.array([sss[z][key] for key in sss[z]])

    cs = [c] * len(xs)
    ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('Second Interval')
ax.set_ylabel('First Interval')
ax.set_zlabel('Frequency')
ax.set_xticklabels(['skip down','step down','stay','step up','skip up'])
ax.set_yticklabels(['','skip down','','step down','','stay','','step up','','skip up'])
ax.set_title('Proportional Frequency of S/S/S Intervals by Previous Interval')

plt.show()
```

`sss` is a dictionary with other dictionaries as values.

Unfortunately I can't post images, but essentially the chart looks all good and all the string labels on the x and y axes work except 'skip up' along the y axis.  It's right at the corner between the y and z axes and just doesn't appear.

What's up?

Comment: Could you post a sample of `sss`?

Comment: You set a fixed list of `yticklabels`. Have you rotated the 3d view to check that you have enough ticks (depending on the view point it is difficult to see which label belongs to which tick). If you dont provide `sss`, you have to reveal its length at least! How many bars do you plot???